# Grails support for WebSphere 7 or 8

Tags: grails, websphere-7

We are using Groovy on Grails framework at my company.  Management wants us to upgrade from WebSphere 6.1 to WebSphere 7 or 8.  Does anyone know if Groovy on Grails is currently supported.

http://grails.org/Deployment does not list WebSphere 7 or 8 as supported.  But I am wondering if someone has had success doing this anyhow.

Does anyone know if WAS7 or 8 is supported in grails, or does anyone have any experience deploying to it?

Comment: I can't think there'd be any reason why it wouldn't work, it's probably just an outdated page.  You could try with an eval copy of WAS 7 or 8.

Answer (score 2):

We have had some success using Grails 1.3.7 on WAS 7, but not Grails 2.0.0.  There seems to be  issues with Spring Security and how WAS deals with the filters that Grails creates.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run a Grails 2.1 app on WAS 8.5 (liberty profile). I encountered an issue with an older, incompatible version of SLF4j in the WAS platform lib, but worked around it by setting a parent-last classloader policy.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten simple grails applications to deploy on both WebSphere 7 and 8 using Grails 1.31. The only issue's I've had are when using the ant builder to send email. This is do to WebSphere shipping an old version of Ant and loading it instead of the version included with your grails app. This may or may not be an issue for you. This issue is mentioned in the deployment notes at
http://www.grails.org/Deployment
under the heading "I get an error like 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement: method setNamespace(Ljava/lang/String;)V not found' what do I do?"

Answer (score 0):

WAS contains many "built-In" libraries and dependencies. I've come across the same issues deploying aspectJ 1.6 onto WAS 7 since the WAS loads by default its own libraries before deploying and staring your application.

The turn around for this is clearly to change the loading Policy. However, be careful with this since you can run into other kinds of errors at the server level.